# How to tell if a bank is legitimate?

Tags: banking, scams, online-banking

I’ve got a deposit on a bank named First Unify Bank, but I can’t really find alot about them online.
Can someone help me find out if the bank is legitimate or not?
Their site is firstunifybk.com

Comment: You deposit your money into a bank which you don't know if it is legitimate?

Comment: What do you mean "got a deposit on a bank"? Did you deposit money or did someone send you money from that bank?

Comment: Also, this: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/141378/how-to-check-if-a-bank-is-legit?rq=1

Comment: You don't get deposit on some random bank. You get deposit on **your** bank where you already have a bank account!

Comment: The website was only registered back in of March of 2022

Answer (score 3):

It does not seem legitimate. The only Google Search hit is their own website and it does indeed look fake.