# Is European Economic Commission Cost Conversion Clearance Certification Code required

Tags: scams, international-transfer

My boyfriend was doing wire transfer to the Philippines from his online bank account in a European bank. Transfer was not effected and asked for COT. Bank said his money still liquid and he needs to pay $3K to be issued the EUROPEAN ECONOMIC COMMISSION COST CONVERSION CLEARANCE CERTIFICATON COT because his money was not programmed in the server for MT103/KTT202 cash backed system. Is this a scam

Comment: Yes, this is a scam. See https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/100166/i-was-asked-for-a-cot-code-to-transfer-money-to-my-account-is-this-a-scam

Comment: Regarding "EUROPEAN ECONOMIC COMMISSION COST CONVERSION CLEARANCE CERTIFICATON COT", is there a typo in "CERTIFICATON", or did you copy that verbatim?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I was asked for a COT code to transfer money to my account. Is this a scam?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/100166/i-was-asked-for-a-cot-code-to-transfer-money-to-my-account-is-this-a-scam)

Comment: As usual, there is no such thing as COT where the recipient pays the payer in order to get paid.