# Is an OTC code a legitimate code for a transfer from the UK to here in the USA?

Tags: international-transfer

I tried to make an international transfer from the UK to here in the USA and was stopped halfway through the process and asked for an OTC code. Is this a legitimate code?

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/100166/i-was-asked-for-a-cot-code-to-transfer-money-to-my-account-is-this-a-scam/

Comment: At least they reordered the letters this time...

Answer (score 7):

The whole transaction is a scam. See many other answers. There is no money. Walk away. And report it to you bank.

If you have given them any of your personal information -- social security number, bank password, birthday, relatives -- they may attempt other attacks using those.